# candle pair count pine script trading view

Tags: pine-script, counter, tradingview-api, algorithmic-trading, candlesticks

`why pair counter in my code not working

pine script v5

Example:
GGGG RR should be count as 1 Pair
the if it again happen say GG RRRR then that should be (previous pair+1)
Candle body should be more than 5 (abs(open-close)>5)
Close should be above (10,3)

If close goes below supertrend then pair counter reset to 0 again
then start again as pair 1,2.. as the case may be.

@vitruvius I am looking similar solution in my post with few tweaks.

Here is your post
[count the number of green candles after each red candle untill we reach to the next green candle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76326672/count-the-number-of-green-candles-after-each-red-candle-untill-we-reach-to-the-n)

I also want to put counter on string of same color candle streak which increase to +1 as the candle streak change color and also meet few other conditions listed below.

```
Close (0) > Supertrend
ABS(Open-Close)>5
Counter reset to 0 if Close<Supertrend
```

`      Screenshot reference:
https://postimg.cc/T5YpyxPD

```
Code reference at pastebin https://pastebin.com/aHshdTkG
```

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your code.:)

Comment: Apologies
And thankyou for your reply.
here is pastebin
https://pastebin.com/aHshdTkG

Comment: any help would be great.

Comment: 10 days gone still no answers :(